# dispatch usereducer in gatsby

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, gatsby, use-reducer

I am new to gatsby and hope you can all helt me.
I am getting a typeerror: dispatch is not a function message, and have stuggled with finding my typo for two days now. I am trying to make a cart and need to pass the product to a global state. It is only when I set in the dispatch in my handleClick function I seem to get the problem (function works with only a console.log and takes in the product fine)

This is my code. First the provider, then the layout and last the template that holds a single product:

```
const CartStateContext = createContext();
const CartDispatchContext = createContext();
const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "ADD":
            return [...state, action.item];
        default: 
        throw new Error(`unknown action ${action.type}`);
    }
};

export const CartProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [ state, dispatch ] = useReducer(reducer, [])

    return (
        <CartDispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
            <CartStateContext.Provider value={state}>
                {children}
            </CartStateContext.Provider>
        </CartDispatchContext.Provider>
        
    )
};

export const useCart = () => useContext(CartStateContext);
export const useDispatchCart = () => useContext(CartDispatchContext);

/* layout component */

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Container from './Container';
import Footerone from './Footerone/Footerone';
import HeaderOne from './HeaderOne/HeaderOne';
import ShopHeaderOne from './ShopHeaderOne/ShopHeaderOne';
import { CartContext } from './CartContext';
import { CartProvider } from './Cart'

export default ({ children }) => { 
    const[cartVisible, setCartVisible] = useState(false);

    const toggleCart = () => {
        setCartVisible(!cartVisible)
    };


    return (
        <Container>   
            <CartProvider>      
                <CartContext.Provider value={{ cartVisible, toggleCart}}>
                    <HeaderOne />
                    <ShopHeaderOne />
                    { children }
                    <Footerone />
                </CartContext.Provider> 
            </CartProvider>
        </Container>
     )
}

/* singleproduct */

import React from 'react'
import Layout from "../Components/Layout"
import './templates.scss'
import { useDispatchCart } from '../Components/Cart';

export default ( props ) => {
  const product = props.pageContext
  const dispatch = useDispatchCart();


  const handleClick = (item) => {
    dispatch({ type: "ADD", item }) 
  }

  console.log(product)

    return (  
        <Layout>         
            <section className="single-grid">
              <h1>{product.headline}</h1>
              <img src={product.image.mediaItemUrl} alt={product.image.altText}/>
              <p>{product.price}</p>
                <button onClick={handleClick(product)}>Føj til kurv</button>
            </section>       
        </Layout>
    )
}
```

Comment: I Have just found out that my dispatch comes up undefined, when console loged. I dont know if it narrows the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried binding directly the `dispatch`?

```
return (  
    <Layout>         
        <section className="single-grid">
          <h1>{product.headline}</h1>
          <img src={product.image.mediaItemUrl} alt={product.image.altText}/>
          <p>{product.price}</p>
            <button onClick={()=>  dispatch({ type: "ADD", item })}>Føj til kurv</button>
        </section>       
    </Layout>
)
```

If the issue persists, check the `reducer` in order to see if it's being set properly.

Comment: Hi thanks for answering. sadly it still did not work. I am not sure how to check the reducer, but I found out that if I console.log the useDispatchCart outside of my fuction I can see it. but as soon as i try putting it in a const og inside the function it comes up undefined

Comment: So the context it seems to be `undefined`?

Comment: if I say:
const dispatch = useDispatchCart()
console.log(dispatch); i get undefined.
but if i say console.log(useDispatchCart) i get it

Comment: Can you provide the log? Maybe you need to destructurate the dispatcher `const { dispatch}  = useDispatchCart()`

Comment: I have found some of the answer now. When working with Gatsby, it will not work to wrap a provider around the layout. You have to make a gatsby-ssr.js and a gatsby-browser.js file and declare the state here.
https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-ssr/#wrapRootElement

I still hav not made it work. When I do I will post the answer.